# Bug: links on badges page in help center

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, help

[image: Screen shot of top of Participation Badges section showing anchor html tags]

Initially I thought this was just in the Participation badges section, but it looks like everywhere on the Badges page that has a link, the anchor html tag is visible.

Comment: Yup, good spot. I've had a look over the other sites and it's a problem there as well. It's been logged on the main Meta StackOverflow site - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191342/several-badge-descriptions-contain-raw-html so, as that's the main site for such global bugs, it's likely any updates will be added over there first. However if I see a resolution to this I'll add an answer here.

Comment: Thanks! I should have thought to check out main SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed, see this [meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191342/several-badge-descriptions-contain-raw-html) for details.